# ios automation test counters error then stop, how to avoid this?

Tags: ios, automation

automation test woorks well except when it couters eror, the excution of script will stop.

Is there a way to tell automation replay go to next function test without stop?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `try catch` statement provided by JavaScript.

For example.

```
function myTest () {
    // do testing here
}

try {
    myTest();
} catch (err) {
    UIALogger.logMessage("ERROR: " + err);
    // go to next testing...
}
```